# GcmBroadcastReceiver not fired on Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I've implemented **GCM** in my app, following this [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html).
But my users under **Android 4.0.3** reported me notifications are not working. I found out that `onReceive` from my `GcmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver` wasn't fired.
Here is my Manifest.

```
    <!-- GCM -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.myapp.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        ... >

        <!-- GCM -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.myapp.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.myapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your application's main package name com.nyapp.gcm or com.myapp?

In the permission part of the manifest you use com.myapp.gcm while in the category of the intent filter of the receiver you use com.myapp.

In both places you should you the same package,  which is the main package of your app.

Comment: Oops, yes you're right, thanks. It's 'com.myapp'. I'm gonna ask my users to try again after an update. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the action "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" in your filter, without which your app will not be able to receive a registration Id. Add the following to your intent-filter:

action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"

Comment: The official documentation doesn't mention it (check the link I provided). Anyway, everything is working above 4.0.3, so I don't think this might be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- GCM -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Your Manifest file permissions missing check BroadcastReceiver registration in manifest file**