# GCM onReceive method not fired on Android 4.0.3 but works on OS above 4.0.3

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am writing an android app (minSDK="14") with GCM push notification.  App works fine on  android higher then 4.0.3(receiving push notification), but on 4.0.3 app don't receive any notification at all.

Already checked: 

[GcmBroadcastReceiver onReceive method not fired on Android 4.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005040/gcmbroadcastreceiver-onreceive-method-not-fired-on-android-4-0-3) and 
[GcmBroadcastReceiver not fired on Android 4.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824058/gcmbroadcastreceiver-not-fired-on-android-4-0-3)

All permission and package are correct,server part is ok(receive success from GCM ), yet not getting notification,
also android support library in my project is 'android-support-v13.jar'

Answer (score 1):

For my apps, I use GCMIntentService

> public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService
>   {

```
public GCMIntentService()
{
    super(senderId);
}

/**
 * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message)
{
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification;
    PendingIntent intent;// = YourPendingIntent;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    {

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        builder.setTicker(message);
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));
        builder.setContentText(message);
        builder.setContentIntent(intent);
        notification = new Notification.BigTextStyle(builder).bigText(message).build();
    }
    else
    {

        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, message, System.currentTimeMillis());
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    }

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
{

    Log.d("GCM", "MESSAGE RECEIVED");
    Bundle b = arg1.getExtras();
    generateNotification(   arg0, b.getString("body"));
}
```

}

In your manifest add to your application these lines:

```
        <receiver
        android:name="my.package.name.GCMReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="my.package.name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".GCMIntentService"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

And to finish

```
    public class GCMReceiver extends GCMBroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context) { 
        Log.i("Receiver", "renaming GCM service");
        return "my.package.name.GCMIntentService";
        }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest mechanism offered by Google that provides GcmListenerService class, extend this class and override the onMessageRecieved(String from,Bundle data) method.